# Manga/manwhua where a boy and his uncle are transported into the video game they both play

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, video-games, isekai

So I remember part of the beginning plot. A brother and sister live with their abusive uncle. The boy plays a game that is not pay-to-win and is in first place. His uncle also plays the game and deletes the brother's save. Then they get Isekaied into the game and he becomes overpowered again to find his sister.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Can you describe any of the characters?  (Hair colour, facial hair, glasses, body type, etc.)  What kind of a game is it?

Comment: It’s a fantasy game where I read it I don’t know anymore but an internet site no glasses black hair I think and he has a castle somehow last year in September and he can summon like op things and he teaches a cat girl magic I can explain how he he showed her but not exactly hope this could help